# Bloomberg API Quote Recap Monitor

Tags: r, excel, api, bloomberg

If you type QRM on a Bloomberg Terminal, you can view intraday ETF quotes for a certain period of time (I think it's 90 days).

Is there a possibility to get these data via the Bloomberg API in a certain time window, say 5 minutes? (Bid/Ask prices)

I tried the intraday version of BLP but I dont know the correct field name. It didn't work for "Bid".

Comment: I don't think so, but try <help><help>.  Their support is pretty good and you pay a fortune for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.

In Excel, go to the Bloomberg tab in the strip, choose Import Data, then Real-Time/Historical, then Historical intraday ticks. The wizard guides you through choosing the date range and which ticks to take.

You can also use Api v3 to get this information, please refer to the developer guide: 
http://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.openbloomberg.com%2Ffiles%2F2012%2F03%2Fblpapi-developers-guide.pdf&ei=1hozU9CLLvLb7AbmyoFY&usg=AFQjCNF3SsHRtum6yKyQ0oeRdrKU9Kwr3g&sig2=SJcFTMFrGdoQ2QO3mbD8bg&bvm=bv.63738703,d.ZGU

6.2.3 Intraday Tick Request

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, allow me to mention that Whit, John and I released a new package [Rblpapi](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rblpapi.html) to CRAN which you can install directly via

```
  install.packages("Rblpapi")
```

It does not depends on Java, and works on Windows, OS X and Linux.

The package has a function 'getTicks()' which does what you want. Here is a futures example (as it is now Sunday evening):

```
R> getTicks("ES1 Index", startTime=Sys.time()-15, endTime=Sys.time())
                      value size
2015-08-23 19:49:47 1960.25    1
2015-08-23 19:49:54 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:57 1960.25    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    7
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    2
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    2
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    9
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:49:59 1960.50    2
2015-08-23 19:50:00 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:00 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:00 1960.50    3
2015-08-23 19:50:01 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    4
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
2015-08-23 19:50:02 1960.50    1
R>
```

That is just trades. We also added a function `getMultipeTicks()` which gets (by default) also Bid and Ask (and other types can be specified).